# AWS Cron Expression - all days @ 11pm but except last day of the month

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch, job-scheduler

I want to write a expression which I want to execute everyday @ 11pm but except last day of the months.

Almost I tried all website I dont get answer to this - saying except last day of the month, it can be 1-30 or 1-29 or 1-28

I tried this expression in Cloudwatch Cron - but it seems it is not correct.

```
0 23 1-L-1 * ? *
```

and,

```
0 23 */L-1 * ? *
```

usually all the questions and answers related to it having answer how to skip first day of the month i.e. days as 2-L, but there were no answer to how pick all the days but not the last day of the month.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is possible at all as you can't do any calculation relative to the `L` wildcard.  Can you change that to "everyday except the first day"? This should be easy.

Comment: NB: In this case, I don't think this would be a duplicate of our standard cron canonical Q&A,  as the AWS cron appears to be only loosely based on the Unix cron syntax and is not mentioned in the canonical Q&A pair.